# Did Optimus Prime, Jazz, Sideswipe, Mirage and Windcharger ever turn into a combiner again?

Tags: transformers

In [episode 64](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0733023/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) of the Transformers G1 cartoon, Optimus Prime, Jazz, Sideswipe, Mirage and Windcharger disguise as the Stunticons. Then Megatron asks them to turn into Menasor, to see if they were the originals or fake ones, and using Windcharger's magnetic field, they turn into a copy of Menasor. The original Menasor fights them, and in the first clash, the original Menasor is knocked down by a punch of the fake Menasor, proving they werent completely useless as a fake combiner. Finally, the original Menasor uses a sword and breaks the fake Menasor down into its original parts.

Was this "combiner" ever portrayed in comics or something?
Did Optimus Prime, Jazz, Sideswipe, Mirage and Windcharger ever turn into a combiner again?

Comment: It never happened in the G1 comic, sadly...